# Is this a valid method to control the FWER?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cross-validation, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, out-of-sample

I have a huge number, say $M$, of hypotheses that are potentially correlated. I have a dataset $D$ of random samples from an unknown distribution and I want to do test the hypotheses for significance using $D$, while controlling the FamilyWise Error Rate (FWER) to be, say, at most $\delta$.

Some people have suggested me to use the following method, but I don't think it is statistically valid, and they can't seem to be able to argue about its being valid, so I thought about asking here.

It is basically the holdout method but used in a multiple hypotheses testing setting.

Take the dataset $D$, split it randomly into two datasets $D_{exp}$ and $D_{eval}$. Use $D_{exp}$ to filter out some of the $M$ hypotheses, for example testing them using critical value $\delta$ (i.e. with no multiple hypotheses correction). Suppose that only $k$ of them pass the test on $D_{exp}$. Test these $k$ on $D_{eval}$, using $\delta/k$ as critical value (or equivalently, using the Holm-Bonferroni method on those $k$ hypotheses), and accept those that pass this test.

The idea is that $k\ll M$ and therefore this method has more power than applying the Bonferroni inequality directly (which is actually computationally infeasible in my case, as $M$ is potentially of the order of $10^{300}$.).

Does this method actually control the FWER? If so why, and is there a reference for this, possibly with a proof? I believe it's of key importance that I'm in a multiple hypotheses testing setting, with potentially correlated hypotheses.

Thanks in advance.